# How to find all files in dir from a specific date (not n days ago) as one-liner?

Tags: linux

How can I modify this command to instead find all files from November 1st, 2014 - and (preferably) on one single line?

```
find /some_path/ -mtime -10 -type f -exec basename {} \;
```

Comment: Why does it have to be one-liner? Homework?

Comment: I intend to use it like this: `rsync --progress --files-from=<(find /src_path -mtime -10 -type f -exec basename {} \;) /src_path /dst_path` and put that into crontab. This is for work (no homework).

Comment: Don't try to force everything into one line for the sake of `cron`. Shell scripts have been invented for a reason.

Comment: One-liner or not, can you define a specific date rather than `-mtime -10` days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New `find` versions have an `-newerXY` option, which can be used in the form `-newermt "2014-11-01"`. You will likely have to do two tests, for newer than 2014-30-31 and for *not* newer than 2014-11-01` or something along this line.

For older versions, you have to feed your date into `date` and do some math with it do get the days since this day.